# ASUS UL30VT - starting recovery partition through console/command

Tags: windows-7, boot-partition

Is there a chance to use or start the recovery setup through the `cmd.exe`?
I booted with a windows 7 pro usb stick and entered the cmd. I can switch into c:\, which is the recovery partition.

The recovery partition doesn't show up in my windows boot loader (F9).
I tried the `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot` but the recovery partition isn't showing up. I only get a windows7 error, which says that the installed windows isn't accessible (because I deleted it).

Deleted versions = fedora 15 and windows 7 pro 64bit (dual usage)
Recovery partition = Windows 7 Home Premium x64